# How can i get webpage network title DOMContentLoaded by curl

Tags: curl, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, domcontentloaded, google-pagespeed-insights-api

[image: 1]

1.Beaucause i want to curl web page : https://m.momoshop.com.tw/main.momo to get DOMContentLoaded seconds,
but curl or postman call web url js don't work,should be curl or postman call web page js not working.

2.so that i want to get DOMContentLoaded BY gogole PageSpeed Insights API, i use curl is get information is ok.
Can i only get DOMContentLoaded seconds not all information .

thank you .

i want to get DOMContentLoaded only by google pagespeed insight api.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this under audits->metrics->details->items->observedDomContentLoaded

It is not possible to get ONLY this from the PageSpeed Insights API. You need to download the full response and then parse the JSON and then extra that information you want.